# How to load type from system dll using Activator.CreateInstance?

Tags: c#, activator

**.Net 4.5.2 and 4.6.2, MSTest unit tests:**

For test-case purposes I need to create 'system' objects by specifying the class name as a string in a data file. I only know the required type at runtime as a string type-name (possibly fully qualified).

I've tried the fairly orthodox approach of

```
            var assyName = "System"; //read from data file
            var typeName = "System.Boolean"; //read from data file
            var hndle = Activator.CreateInstance(assyName, typeName);
            var obj = hndle.Unwrap();
            var t = obj.GetType();
```

but whilst this works if I am loading my own type from my own assemblies, if I try it using a .Net assembly (as above) the *Activator* line throws a FileNotFound exception. I've tried changing the referenced System assembly Copy Local property to true, but that seems to have no effect. I've also tried specifying the full path to the System assembly, without luck.

So the questions are: what am I doing wrong, and (if nothing wrong) how otherwise do I achieve my aim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data file is wrong.

The `System.Boolean` type, just as many other types in the `System` namespace reside in the `mscorlib` assembly, not in the `System` assembly which that data file claims. There is no relation between a namespace name and an assembly name.

You can see which assembly contains a type on that type's MSDN page.

For example [`System.Uri`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx) is in `System.dll`, but [`System.Boolean`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean(v=vs.110).aspx) is in `mscorlib.dll`.

Comment: Well that solved the problem, but I don't understand why, given that it failed to load the System.dll, not that it failed to find the type in it. What do I do if I want the System.Uri type? var hndle = Activator.CreateInstance("System", "System.Uri") still fails with a FileNotFound exception, as does a similar Assembly.Load("path to System dll")

Comment: @NeilHaughton you need to use fully qualified name, like this one: "System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089". Though with Uri that will still not work, because Uri does not have parameterless constructor.